# When you close off the mouth of a vacuum cleaner, is it using more energy?

Tags: energy, work, vacuum

When you close off the mouth of a vacuum cleaner it seems that you let the cleaner do more work (I always have the feeling something is gonna be burned inside) and thus let it use more energy. Now I'm not an expert in the field of vacuum cleaners, so I was wondering if this is actually true. Any expert who can tell me the answer?

Comment: When you close off the mouth of a vacuum cleaner, you're making it more difficult for the propellor connected to the vc's motor to push air through the vc and increasing the drag on the motor. So your question basically reduces to the question of whether the energy consumption of an ac motor increases when you increase the drag on the motor, right?

Comment: Engine turning less fast --->Self inductance current is lower----> the total current that is drawn from the power supply is higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most vacuum cleaners have a universal motor and use a centrifugal pump.
So, with NO air going through, it has a partial vacuum created, and
maintains it, but without doing any work.   It can burn the motor up,
because that air movement also cools the motor, but that isn't because
the motor has extra 'load', it's just lack of cooling.

There is some load due to leakage and viscosity, and the motor does
(at least MINE does) speed up when airflow is blocked.   A wattmeter
on the vacuum shows energy use dropping from 660 W to 520W.
It isn't dramatically less because the faster-moving motor is losing more
energy to air viscosity outside the vacuum flow path.   It doesn't lose
any energy to air viscosity IN the flow path, when the flow is zero.